# Laravel pagination without refresh the page

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

Currently, I am pulling 8 random records from the database ( and then save them in array), and then use Laravel Pagination to divide them to 4 records each pages.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/userInfo','MainController@getUserInfo');
```

**Controller**

```
class MainController extends Controller{
    function getDatabaseInformation{
          // Get information from the database. Return array
    }

    function getUserInfo {
           $userData = $this->getDatabaseInformation();
           $data = $this->paginate($userData );
           $data->withPath('userInfo');
           return view('userDataPage',['userData'=>$data]);
    }

    function paginate($items, $perPage = 4, $page = null, $options = [])
    {
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
    }
}
```

**userDataPage.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Q5S1Q2</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   .box{
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
   }
   .title{
      text-align:center;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />
  <div class = "title">  <h1> User list　</h1></div>
  <div class="container box">
      @foreach($userData as $data)
      <div>
        <p><strong>{{$post->getAddress()}}</strong><br></p>
        <span>{{$post->getFirstName()}}</span>
        <span>{{$post->getLastName()}}</span>
        <span>{{$post->getOccupation()}}</span>
      <br>
      </div>
      @endforeach
  </div>
  <div class = "title"> {{ $userData ->links() }}</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This successfully shows the records divided by 2 pages. However, when I switch between the pages, it refreshes the whole thing - not keeping my "old" pulling records. I think the function *getUserInfo* get run again whenever I switch between pages, thus having different record (since I pick them randomly) ?

Anyone ever having the same problem ? How do I solve this, or is pagination not the correct way ?

(I was thinking of having 2 different blade files (for page 1 and 2) and have a global variable to decide which page to show)

Comment: You should paginate the `records/model` not the `array/collection` itself. One more thing to note that: you will be passing all the required `information/parameters` needed for the method otherwise it will not return the expected output

Comment: You are right, when you are calling the next page, your method will be called again and therefore you probably get a different result. If you want to keep the same result, you have to save the result somewhere so it can be used every time a next/previous page is requested.

Comment: I tried to save the result pulling from database in session and it works. However, is it considered a good practice or should I try to find another way ? @Philip

Comment: I have to admit that I had the same problem and this was my workaround for it. I stored the information in my database for a certain time and then deleted the data. I don´t know, if its the best solution or a good practice, but I have not found another solution for this topic by now.